# Working with Backgroundworker - Results

Tags: object, listbox, backgroundworker

Im trying to get the results from a background worker. I am returning a List of process names back to the main thread to display the processes in a listbox. This is all well and good , i have the result using e.Result as an object , **however** this is the problem. I have the object itself and when i watch the statement i can see the list in the result but im struggling to get it back into the list format. I can give e.Result a ToString and it even shows that the type is a list of strings but obviously i cant turn that to the list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try `var list = e.Result as List<string>;`